# Difference in nuance or meaning between "The result, American officials say…" and "American officials say the result…"

Tags: meaning, word-order, phrase-order

The following is an excerpt from The New York Times of Feb.2. 2023.
If the last sentence reads: "**American officials say** the result has been hundreds of troops killed or injured a day," does it make any difference in the nuance or meaning?

> With Moscow desperate for a major battlefield victory and viewing
> Bakhmut as the key to seizing the entire eastern Donbas area, the
> Russian military has sent poorly trained recruits and former convicts
> to the front lines, straight into the path of Ukrainian shelling and
> machine guns. The result, **American officials say**, has been hundreds of
> troops killed or injured a day.

Summary/Highlight : [ Positioning **American officials say** in the middle ] versus [ Moving that to the Start ]

Comment: Are you asking about what makes the difference between being killed vs. being injured?  Please clarify....

Comment: OP is asking about moving **"American officials say"** , @YosefBaskin

Comment: I hope I have interpreted the Post Correctly , @livresque

Comment: The phrase is so light-weight that there isn't much of anything to be nuanced about. If it were heftier, then there might be something to that suggestion. Either way, it says I'm not making up casualty numbers, other somebodies,  American officials, are making up casualty numbers.

Comment: The difference is that positioning the officials second suggests that the sentence is about the result, not the officials.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference. The sentence:

> The result, **American officials say,** has been hundreds of troops killed or injured a day.

has a more dynamic style. *American officials say* is inserted as an aside, interrupting but not disturbing the flow of the message and increasing the anticipation for the rest. Since it is an aside, the fact that American officials say that is considered less important information than the rest of the sentence.

As for the sentence you suggest

> **American officials say** the result has been hundreds of troops killed or injured a day.

it is more plain than the other variant, since it follows the expected word order. However, here *American officials say* is part of the main message, not supplementary information as in the other sentence.

Quoting Robert A. Harris, *Writing With Clarity and Style: A Guide to Rhetorical Devices for Contemporary Writers. Pyrczak, 2003*, [Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/interrupting-phrase-grammar-and-style-1691179) says:

> The verbal violence involved in stopping one's sentence in order to jump in and present some other information ***grabs the reader's attention in a dramatic way***. It creates the sense that the writer could not wait until the next sentence to make an announcement relevant to the current idea. The emphasis of the interruption is most profound when dashes are used and when the interruption consists of an entire sentence.

The [US Univ. of Sussex](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/bracketing) has an article on *Bracketing Commas*, which explains:

> The rule is this: *a pair of bracketing commas is used to mark off **a weak interruption** of the sentence* — that is, an interruption which does not disturb the smooth flow of the sentence... the weak interruption set off by bracketing commas could, in principle, be removed from the sentence, and the result would still be a complete sentence that made good sense.

Comment: Depending on how you feel about the trustworthiness of American officials, emphasising the phrase by moving "American officials say" to the start could definitely affect how believable the whole sentence is. But it's hard to be sure what was intended just from the excerpt.

Comment: That is the Point I was hinting at , in my Answer Case (A) : "This is what American officials say , though I (or others) do not agree" , which gives the writer wiggle room to change Stance later , @StuartF

Answer (score 1):

Assuming my Interpretation is Correct , the intended "overall" meaning which the writer wants to convey will be Exactly Same , in the sense of what the result is.

The logical Structure changes a little , which might lead to a nuanced "subtle" change in meaning.

**(A)** "American officials say the result has been hundreds of troops killed or injured a day" : this might mean : "This is what American officials say , though I (or others) do not agree"
It talks about what the American officials said.

**(B)** "The result, American officials say, has been hundreds of troops killed or injured a day" : this might mean : "I am sure that is the result , which even the American officials confirm"
It talks about what the result was , taking support from American officials to substantiate the claim.

**(C)** "The result has been hundreds of troops killed or injured a day" : this might mean : "That is the result with no uncertainty"
It talks about what the result was. It is a categorical claim without involving words   from American officials.

The Stylistic Structure changes too , which user "fev" has covered in the Earlier Answer.